# How do I "skip" a scenario with a tag in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I currently have a project with a pretty large pile of Cucumber `.feature` files where many of the Scenarios are known to be broken. These scenarios are tagged with `@broken`, and we avoid running them by executing cucumber with `-t ~@broken`. Unfortunately, this makes these scenarios effectively invisible when we examine the cucumber output. They don't appear as passed, failed, or skipped. What I'd like is for a count of these scenarios to be included in the cucumber output. They should show as "skipped" tests, rather than not showing at all.

What I tried:

```
Before('@broken') do |scenario|
  pending
end
```

But this raises a `Cucumber::Pending` exception which, uncaught, just fails the scenario.

I know I can write a step like:

```
Given /^PENDING/ do
  pending
end
```

And then go through all my feature files and add this step to every scenario with the `@broken` tag. This seems crazy, though. It doesn't fit with the semantics of what a "step" is supposed to be (not to mention that it requires broad changes to all my feature files instead of just adding a hook to a tag).

Is this something I can do with just a tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the question is old, it is still a Google favorite - so for the benefit of future visitors, I am sharing this.

I am tagging my scenarios, and then in my "step_definitions/hooks.rb" file, I have something like this:

```
Before('@proxy') do 
  skip_this_scenario unless proxy_running?
end
```

When running, the scenario is skipped gracefully.

```
1 scenario (1 skipped)
```

Answer (score 2):

EDITED:

According to your comment, you are using cucumber-1.3.10. It is not possible with that version.

In cucumber-jvm and cucumber-js it works as expected marking the scenario as pending, but surprisingly in ruby, if the Pending exception is thrown from the Before (or After) hook, it will mark the scenario as failed instead of pending.

So your first suggestion was right. You should use a tagged hook.

```
Before('@broken') do
 pending
end
```

But you will have to update your Gemfile to use the latest version of cucumber, that is 2.0.0.beta.3 at this moment.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber', '2.0.0.beta.3'
end
```

Then the output will be as expected, marked as pending (not skipped as there is no such thing as a skipped scenario, only passed/failed/pending/undefined/skipped steps and passed/failed/pending/undefined scenarios).

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I said, when I tried to use the the tagged hook, it marked the scenario failed rather than pending. I get the following error:

`TODO (Cucumber::Pending)
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_world.rb:130:in 'pending'
   /Users/me/test/steps/test.rb:6:in 'Before'`

Comment: I see, I have set up a Ruby project and indeed it marks the pending scenarios as failed when the pending exception is thrown from the hook. In cucumber-jvm and cucumber-js, which are the ones I normally use, it works as expected, marking the scenario as pending. I will have a look at the Ruby implementation anyway, and see if there is a workaround. Regards.

Comment: Ok, I have it working now, but you will have to update to the very latest version, 2.0.0.beta.3, I will update my answer.